# Xamarin: Issue with Push arriving in ios app; no issue with arriving when outside of app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We want to capture push notifs when they arrive, even if the user has the app open. This was working a few pushes ago. But has stopped working now. Rolling back does not fix the issue, which makes me wonder if it is a setting in the push message or in the device itself.

Currently pushes arrive when not in the app just fine.
They do not arrive when in the app, and the following AppDelegate code never is fired:

```
   public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(
    UIApplication application,
    NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("com.nnnn.app.log::iOS::ReceivedRemoteNotificatio::Success");
        ProcessNotificationActions(userInfo);
    }
```

Comment: What is the version of you iOS? If you use  iOS 9 and prior, please check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios For iOS 10 and later, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing UNUserNotificationCenter resolved this issue.
Thanks to Wendy Zang for the strong nudge in the right direction.